# Send error message with .htaccess if invalid user

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm setting up .htaccess and .htpasswd files in a subdirectory of a website and I was wondering if its possible to set up a custom error message. Typically you get the following;

***Authorization Required***
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

However, I'd like to change this message. In addition, I'd like to limit the number of attempts to login. I've read that it used to be 3, but its unlimited the way I've set it up. I currently have the following in my .htaccess file.

```
AuthUserFile c:\wamp\.htpasswd
AuthName "localhost"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

I've been trying to read through the apache tutorials about .htaccess but it seems like a maze, if someone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If authorisation fails, you usually get a 401 error.

You can choose what to display when a 401 occurs by adding a line to your `.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 401 /var/www/error/401.html
```

Ideally this should be a static html page (not php or anything that might also error) and make sure that unauthenticated users can access the error page.

Then you can put what you like in it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to try it out after the long weekend.